# Why I should Remove/Save a Session Object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, servicestack

Hi I'm working with Sessions between MVC4 and ServiceStack and don't understand what is the use and when to use the ServiceStack AuthService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry) and the ServiceStack AuthService.RemoveSession()?